# is it possible to turn off automatic uploads and programmatically fire an upload based on a custom event occurring in fine uploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, fine-uploader

According to this website: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/upload-files.html

A developer can disable autoupload by setting the flag `autoUpload: false` and can trigger an upload when the user decides to click on the "upload-button" like:

```
qq(document.getElementById("upload-button")).attach('click', function() {
    uploader.uploadStoredFiles();
});
```

My question is: suppose I have a div tag that looks like:

```
<div class="user" customval="default"></div>
```

and it some point (perhaps 3 or 4 seconds later) the div tag changes to:

```
<div class="user" customval="changed!!!"></div>
```

What would the fine uploader code look like to trigger the file upload and include the custom value "changed!!!" in the file upload request (i.e. I want "changed!!!" to be inside the multi part file upload request and the file upload should be triggered only when the value of "customval" has changed.

Comment: "it possible to trigger an upload based on an event other than a click event?" Yes, of course. Call the `uploadStoredFiles` API method whenever you want to start the upload process.

Comment: @RayNicholus - Great. I modified my question above and if you could provide a code solution for my example above, I will mark it correct.

Comment: The only way to programmatically detect when an element such as a div has changed would be to use mutation observers. What browsers do you need to support? Ideally, you would _not_ have to watch the element, and instead hook into some other function that is called as part of updating this div.

Comment: Let's suppose the hook you are asking about is called "function_hook()" which is a javascript function that will change div element. Web browser is Safari 5 and above on osx

Comment: then add `uploader.uploadStoredFiles()` to the body of that function. If you need more specific code, can you post what you have that illustrates this function and the uploader initialization?

Comment: @RayNicholus - doesnt uploader.uploadStoredFiles() need to be inside the qq(document.getElementById("upload-button")). statement ? How will the scope of function_hook() know what "uploader" is?

Comment: Simple, when you `new` up your uploader, store the variable containing the upload instance. Reference it later when you want to call an API method on that uploader.